# Uno Platform app react to Android theme change

Tags: uno-platform

While for the most part Uno Platform apps are able to handle theme changes internally,
I have some custom code in my app that needs to react to theme change. For example when user changes from light them to dark theme here:

[Android display settings for theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBHq9.png)

In my code I can get the theme value initially like this:

```
var color = (Color)App.Current.Resources["SystemBaseHighColor"]
```

Now when the user changes theme and returns to the app I want to detect that and programmatically update some component. Is there an event I can hook into for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for theme changes on all platforms using the [`ThemeListener` helper class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.helpers.themelistener) from the [Windows Community Toolkit](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/uno-community-toolkit.html?tabs=tabid-vswin). It's supported by recent Uno Platform versions.

Just create a new instance of `ThemeListener` and subscribe to the `ThemeListener.ThemeChanged` event.